# Issues with music player in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've been working on a music player in Unity. It gets the audioclips from an array within Unity, and a random number generator picks a clip between 0 and the size set in Unity. However, nothing stops it from picking the same number (and thus same song) twice in a row which is something I do not want. I've been trying a few things but ended up with a NullReferenceException. If you'd like to take a look I'd greatly appreciate it!

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class MusicPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Variables

    //Variables needed for this code
    public AudioClip[] clips;

    private AudioSource audioSource;

    string currentTitle = "";

    #endregion

    #region Start Void
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //Finds AudioSource in the unity editor and turns off the "loop" function.
        audioSource = FindObjectOfType<AudioSource>();
        audioSource.loop = false;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private AudioClip
    //The code below will grab a random audio clip between 0 and the amount set in the Unity Editor.
    private AudioClip GetRandomClip()
    {
        return clips[Random.Range(0, clips.Length)];

    }
    #endregion

    #region Update Void
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {


        if (audioSource.clip.name.Length >= 0)
        {
            currentTitle = audioSource.clip.name;
        }

        if (!audioSource.isPlaying)
        {
            var nextTitle = currentTitle;
            ulong index = 0;
            while (nextTitle == currentTitle)
            {
                index = (ulong) Random.Range(0, clips.Length);
                nextTitle = clips[index].name;
            }
            audioSource.Play(index);
        }


    }
    #endregion
}
```

Went back into my code to prepare it for future stuff as well like calling audio clips from multiple arrays and with the help of both Silleknarf and derHugo I got it worked out. Thank you all so much. Here is the code I ended up with:

```
/*
    AudioPlayer.cs
    RTS Game

    Created by Robin den Ambtman on 17-06-2019
    Copyright © Robinblitz. All rights reserved.
*/

using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;

public class AudioPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Variables

    //Variables needed for this code

    [Header("Sound arrays")]
    public AudioClip[] musicClips;
    [Space(10)]
    public AudioClip[] announcerClips;
    [Space(10)]
    public AudioClip[] TBDClips;

    [Header("Effect/Music sources")]
    public AudioSource effectAudioSource;
    public AudioSource musicAudioSource;

    #endregion

    #region Start Void
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //Finds AudioSource in the unity editor and turns off the "loop" function.
        musicAudioSource.loop = false;
        Random.InitState((int)System.DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Music RNG
    //The code below will grab a random audio clip between 0 and the amount of clips set in the Unity Editor.
    private AudioClip GetRandomMusicClip()
    {

        // This returns only those clips that are not the currenty played one
        var filteredClips = musicClips.Where(c => c != musicAudioSource.clip).ToArray();

        return filteredClips[Random.Range(0, filteredClips.Length)];
    }
    #endregion

    #region Update Void
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //If the audio source is playing it will grab the song that's picked out by GetRandomClip() and plays it.
        if (!musicAudioSource.isPlaying)
        {
            var newTitle = GetRandomMusicClip();
            musicAudioSource.clip = newTitle;
            musicAudioSource.Play();
        }

        //Piece of code as a test to play a specific audio clip on key press.
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            effectAudioSource.PlayOneShot(effectAudioSource.clip, 0.7f);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: If you dont want it to pick the same one in a row, add a memory of the id of the last played and if picked pick again

Comment: I'm quite new to C# and Unity and am not really sure how to do what you've just stated. Could you help me out with it? Would love to try it.

Comment: Well, if you were human, how would you do it.  Probably write the last one on a piece of paper, and then if you pulled the same one out the bucket pick a new one... make a variable store the number  you had last time, if on picking a new one from the random range, ditch it and try again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already mentioed in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58301857/7111561) the parameter of [`AudioSource.Play(ulong)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Play.html) is

> **delay** 
> Deprecated.
>
> Delay in number of samples, assuming a 44100Hz sample rate (meaning that Play(44100) will delay the playing by exactly 1 sec).

So what you want to do is

```
audioSource.clip = newClip;
audioSource.Play();
```

---

Then I would rather suggest using [Linq `Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) and filter the unwanted (= currently playing) clip out beforehand without any `while`-loop like

```
using System.Linq;

...

private AudioClip GetRandomClip()
{
    // This returns only those clips that are not the currenty played one
    var filteredClips = clips.Where(c => c != audioSource.clip).ToArray();

    return filteredClips[Random.Range(0, filteredClips.Length)];
}

void Update()
{
    if (!audioSource.isPlaying)
    {
        var newTitle = GetRandomClip();
        audioSource.clip = newTitle;
        audioSource.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried the things you've mentioned above and VS2019 comes back with a compile error: `AudioClip[]' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no accessible extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'AudioClip[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` @derHugo

Comment: @Robinblitz seems that you forgot to add the `using System.Linq;` to the top of your script

Comment: Oh yeah haha. I made a new script to try this out and forgot to add it... Stupid me!

Comment: @silleknarf I have updated the code with the working solution from you both. Figured out I had way different code at home instead of on my laptop so I went from there and this is what I got now. Thank you both so much!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't set the clip for the audioSource using the [`audioSource.clip`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-clip.html) property. Perhaps it would be easier to change the `string currentTitle` variable to be a `AudioClip currentClip` and then just use the `currentClip.title` property when doing the equality comparisons. Then at the end just before you call the `audioSource.Play()` method you can set the clip as follows: `audioSource.clip = nextTitle;`.

Another thing to note is that the parameter to the [`audioSource.Play`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Play.html) method is the delay rather than the index of the clip to play so you need to set the clip first and probably don't even need to pass a parameter to the `audioSource.Play` method.

Comment: Tried it and I'm still getting the NullReferenceException in line 42 which is `if (audioSource.clip.name.Length >= 0)`

Comment: In the first iteration of the update method, you haven't set the clip for the audioSource. Perhaps to fix it, you could, in your start method initialise the `audioSource.clip` value, like this: `audioSource.clip = GetRandomClip();`.

Comment: Did what you've just said, I've at least got audio for half a second but then it just cuts out and doesn't finish the audio file from the array. And it starts always at the first one of the array.

Comment: Please can you add section to your question with an update to your code?